# TCPDF Wrapping Text around an object

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Simple question.  Let's say that I have a Cell full of text and I want to have a smaller Cell in the middle that has some related information in it.  Is there function or feature in TCPDF that allows text in the bigger cell to wrap cleanly around the text in the smaller, inner cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at the 'new no-write page regions' example.

[PHP] - http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_064.phps
[PDF] - http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_064.pdf

it uses the new setPageRegions() function. I used it for a project recently. I blogged about the effect [Dynamic PDFs – TCPDF setPageRegions() Function](http://www.youinspire.me.uk/dynamic-pdfs-tcpdf-setpageregions-function/) which has a screen shot of the result - very cool!

Hope that helps.
Josh

Comment: it is hard to calculate where the image is, if you have a dynamic text, is there some other options?